# php private vars questions ... (acessible trought var_dump)?

Tags: php, class

Is there anyway to prevent var_dump from printing private vars in a class? I got a private var for DBPASS and this surely shouldn't be printed when using

```
var_dump($this->db);
```

as

```
["db_host:private"]=> string(9) "localhost" ...user, pass, etc ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway to prevent var_dump from printing private vars in a class?

No, you can't. Note that private variables were **not** made to hide passwords - at least not in the sense that you are implying. Arguably they could all the public and it would make little difference to the security of your application, if that's what you are concerned about.

> I got a private var for DBPASS and this surely shouldn't be printed when using var_dump

You have full control over where `var_dump()` is used, it's not like it magically pops up to show your password to an end-user. You really shouldn't have any kind of debug code in a production environment anyways.

Comment: Thanks, Im more concerned on some code being injected and doing it. But again, this shouldn't be the case if I secure all possibilities ...

Comment: @Henrique If someone can execute arbitrary code on your server, you've got some serious problems. At that point it wouldn't really matter if `var_dump()` showed private variables or not.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Being $object an instance of your class, If you want to

```
   var_dump($object->db)
```

a Fatal error: Cannot access private property is showed, but you can do

```
   var_dump($object)
```

with no error and th sensible data is showed.

You can use a two ways cypher algorithm to store the password and decypher just to use it.

[mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) can help you.

Comment: This makes little difference, since you need the plaintext password in order to use it, so it's got to be decrypted by PHP at some point. If someone can see your PHP code, they can have your password. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a smart solution.

Comment: You can run a instance of encrypt_pass('XXX') and save the result as plain text, and decrypt_pass when using to connect to the db. But again, if someone can see your code, will get know your decrypt hash. But still make things more difficult. Probably a good solution if you don't store your decrypt hash under some $var avoid some code injection into your system to echo $dbpass.

Comment: If your code is visible, then the password may be visibe too. Store the database password encrypted or base64_encoded in a .ini file out of you app (allowed by open_basedir), and be sure that the user that connect to the database only can connect from localhost. But if somebody can inject code to your app, they can access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide anything from your objects. The idea of the private modifier is to prevent the calling function to change the inner state of the object but not to hide the value from the world.

I made a simple test

```
class A {
    private $num1 = 10;
    public $num2 = 20;
    function __toString(){
        return "My class is secret\n";
    }
    function __get($param){
        echo "__get is called with param = $param\n";
    }
}

$a = new A;

echo $a;
var_dump($a);
```

Here are the results:

```
My class is secret
object(A)#1 (2) {
  ["num1":"A":private]=>
  int(10)
  ["num2"]=>
  int(20)
}
```

So neither `__toString`, nor `__get` is called when `var_dump` is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create your own wrapper function around `var_dump` that took the result of a raw `var_dump` and replaced the line after any key that looks like `[xxxx:yyyy:private]=>` with a blank line.